# Pros and cons separating Web API and Client?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, architecture, single-page-application, conceptual

It's good to separate Web API and Client for maintainability and distribution, but are there any other pros and cons doing it?

For example, performance. Will it significantly affect application startup time? I guess it's faster to start one application rather then start Client wait until the page is loaded and only upon first request to the server the Web API application will be started.

In general, do you need to worry about that or you can just do it? There is only one case that comes to my mind over not doing it - specific deployment requirements.

Comment: did you find any answer?